# How to prevent Ajax GET to refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal that I constructed dynamically using **jquery**.

[image]

When I click on yes. I called this ajax

---

I've tried

```
var popupTemplate =
'<div class="modal fade">' +
'  <div class="modal-dialog">' +
'    <div class="modal-content">' +
'      <div class="modal-header">' +
'        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>' +
'        <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure ?</h4>' +
'      </div>' +
'      <div class="modal-body">' +
'        <h4 class="modal-title">You want to ' + operation + '  ' +  instance + ' ?</h4>' +
'      </div>' +
'      <div class="modal-footer">' +
'        <a id="updateAction" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ' +
'        onclick="updateAction(`'+ instance+'`);return false;">Yes</a>' +
'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>' +
'      </div>' +
'    </div>' +
'  </div>' +
'</div>';

$(popupTemplate).modal();

    $('#updateAction').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        alert("HIIIII");
        // or use return false;
        console.log("event.preventDefault() executed ... ");
        return false;
    });
```

I added an id, and add `event.preventDefault();`

> My click() function doesn't seem to trigger

As soon as I add that block of ajax, I notice my page keep refreshing.

If I remove that block of ajax my page is not refreshed.

**How do I stop the **Refreshing**?**

Comment: can you try to replicate this in a codepen for us to look into? thanks

Comment: Also, i would suggest you try to use something different than an <a> tag, and be sure you don't have an href="#" (this will append the # in the url and might be an issue)

Comment: $('#updateAction').on('click', function (event) {...})

Comment: You have a onclick="updateAction" where is this function? But if you're  $('#updateAction').click listen to it, you'll probably not going to need onclick="updateAction(`'+ instance+'`);return false;" at all. Also, be sure to wrap this up with document ready.

Comment: Ajax Get doesn't refresh the page.

Comment: block of ajax?  There is no ajax.

Comment: @James I suspect he meant "block of JavaScript"

Comment: What does `updateAction()` do? If it stops because of an error, you won't execute `return false`, and then the page will refresh.

Comment: 1) Two different event handlers are assigned.  2) it’s possible that `#updateAction` does not quite exist when you try to bind the jquery click handler to it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `href="#"` to the anchor, so if there an error in `updateAction()` it won't try to follow the link and reload the page.

Comment: Okay. Let me try.